# construct a chain using two columns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and struggling with data formatting with the below data frame :

```
Col1    Col2
Type1   Type2
Type3   Type4
Type8   Type13
Type3   Type15
Type2   Type6
Type4   Type9
Type6   Type11
Type9   Type18
Type13  Type20
```

I want to identify the chain like format using `col1` and `col2`. For example `Type1-->Type2-->Type6-->Type11` form a chain.So the final result will look as below :

```
Col1    Col2    Chain
Type1   Type2   Chain1
Type3   Type4   Chain2
Type8   Type13  Chain3
Type3   Type15  
Type2   Type6   Chain1
Type4   Type9   Chain2
Type6   Type11  Chain1
Type9   Type18  Chain2
Type13  Type20  Chain3
```

Comment: 1) This has nothing to do with formatting. 2) Isn't the `col1-to-`col2` relationship defining a directed edge? In that case wouldn't it be better to call them *from* and *to*?

Comment: So why chain2 is formed by 3-4-9-18 instead of 3-15? How do decide this?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco - FCFS basis.

Comment: I don't think a `DataFrame` is a very good data structure for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do something like this (you need to install `networkx`). Note that `df` is your Dataframe containing all your data:

```
import networkx as nx

edges = df.drop_duplicates(['Col1'])
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edges.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
ccs = list(nx.connected_components(G))
df['Chain'] = df.apply(lambda row: next((f'Chain{i}' for i, cc in enumerate(ccs) if row[0] in cc and row[1] in cc), ''), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     Col1    Col2   Chain
0   Type1   Type2  Chain0
1   Type3   Type4  Chain1
2   Type8  Type13  Chain2
3   Type3  Type15        
4   Type2   Type6  Chain0
5   Type4   Type9  Chain1
6   Type6  Type11  Chain0
7   Type9  Type18  Chain1
8  Type13  Type20  Chain2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    "Col1": ["Type1", "Type3", "Type8", "Type3", "Type2", "Type4", "Type6", "Type9", "Type13"],
    "Col2": ["Type2", "Type4", "Type13", "Type15", "Type6", "Type9", "Type11", "Type18", "Type20"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Efficiently group nodes and assign chain IDs using NetworkX
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Col1', 'Col2', create_using=nx.Graph())
print(G)#Graph with 12 nodes and 9 edges
components = list(nx.connected_components(G))
"""print(components)
[{'Type2', 'Type11', 'Type1', 'Type6'},
{'Type9', 'Type18', 'Type3', 'Type4', 'Type15'},
 {'Type20', 'Type8', 'Type13'}]
"""
chain_ids = {node: f"Chain_{i}" for i, component in enumerate(components) for node in component}
"""print(chain_ids)
{'Type2': 'Chain_0', 'Type11': 'Chain_0', 'Type6': 'Chain_0', 
'Type1': 'Chain_0', 'Type18': 'Chain_1', 'Type15': 'Chain_1', 'Type9': 'Chain_1', 
'Type3': 'Chain_1', 'Type4': 'Chain_1', 'Type13': 'Chain_2', 'Type20': 'Chain_2', 'Type8': 'Chain_2'}
"""  
    # Add "Chain" column with correct chain IDs
df['Chain'] = df['Col1'].map(chain_ids)
print(df)
"""   Col1    Col2    Chain
0   Type1   Type2  Chain_0
1   Type3   Type4  Chain_1
2   Type8  Type13  Chain_2
3   Type3  Type15  Chain_1
4   Type2   Type6  Chain_0
5   Type4   Type9  Chain_1
6   Type6  Type11  Chain_0
7   Type9  Type18  Chain_1
8  Type13  Type20  Chain_2
"""
```